# Comparing aggregate function across different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables as below which have duplicate records. I need to fetch records which are present in both tables, have duplicate rows and number of duplicates are more in table 2

```
Table 1

A     B      C     D     E
192   168    101   100   32
192   168    101   100   32
192   168    101    102  30
192   168    101   102   30
```

Table 2

```
A     B      C     D     E
192   168    101   100   32
192   168    101   100   32
192   168    101   100   32
192   168    101   102   30
```

For Example I need to fetch the records 192 168 101 100 32 because its occurrence is more in table 2 than table 1.I know how to get count from individual tables but how to compare count with two tables for every tuple

```
select A,B,C,D, count(*) from table1 inner join table 2 on table1.A=table2.A and table1.B=table2.B and table1.c=table2.c and table1.d=table2.d group by A,B,C,D having count(table2.A,table2.B,table2.C,table2.D)>count(table1.A,table1.B,table1.c,table.D)
```

The query above is syntactically incorrect but I am thinking to do something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D, t1.E
 FROM (
   SELECT A,B,C,D,E, count(*) AS cnt
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY A,B,C,D,E
  ) t1
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT A,B,C,D,E, count(*) AS cnt
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY A,B,C,D,E
  ) t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B AND t1.C = t2.C AND t1.D = t2.D AND t1.E = t2.E
 WHERE t1.cnt < t2.cnt
```

Test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/994119/1